# Definition of $\sigma$-finite

Tags: measure-theory

From wikipedia:

> A set in a measure space $X$ is said to have $\sigma$-finite measure
>   if it is a countable union of sets with finite measure.

Quick and easy question about the definition: Suppose a set $E$ is $\sigma$-finite, and let $\{E_{n}\}_{1}^{\infty}$ be a countable sequence of disjoint sets such that:

$$\bigcup_{1}^{\infty} E_{n} = E$$

Do we know whether the sets in either $\{E_{n}\}$ have finite measure? Or is the definition just saying "there exists a sequence of sets with finite measure whose union is $E$"? Where in the second case the sequence is abstract and the only thing we know is that it exists.

I believe it is the latter, but any clarification would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I had something in mind comparing the two sequences, but I cant imagine what it was. The inclusion of two sequences is redundant, so I have deleted one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could happen that *some* decomposition of a $\sigma$-finite set into countably many disjoint subsets contains infinite measure sets. For instance, work in $\mathbb{R}$ with $E_1=(-\infty,0)$ and $E_k=[k-2,k-1)$ for $k \geq 2$.

Answer (score 2):

It says "there is" only of course. Take your $E$, $\sigma$-finite but not with finite measure, and put
$$ E_i = \begin{cases} E & \text{if $i=0$} \\ \emptyset & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$

Answer (score 1):

One easy counterexample is something like $\mathbb{R}^2$ with Lebesgue measure (or any measure you like that is translation/rotation-invariant and measures intervals in the usual way): it's $\sigma$-finite since you can cover it with the disks $\{ x:\lvert x \rvert < n \}$, but the sets $[n,n+1) \times \mathbb{R}$ form a disjoint cover of infinite-measure sets.

Answer (score 0):

The definition is just "there exists". The other way is totally not true. Consider $\Bbb{R}$ with the usual measure. Then:

$$\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \Bbb{R} = \Bbb{R}$$

but $\mu (\Bbb{R})=\infty$

Edit: I just saw that you say "disjoint". Well this is still not true.

Consider $E_n=\Bbb{R}$ for $n=1$ and $E_n=\emptyset$ otherwise. There are tons of other counterexamples.

Comment: In the OP the sets in the decomposition are disjoint.